# How does the FederationMetadata.xml get created on the STS

Tags: .net, federation

I'm trying to set up a Relying Party web application to use the newly set up ADFS 2.0, but when I run the `FedUtil.exe`, it cannot locate the `Federationmetadata.xml` file on the STS.

I've searched the server for this document, but it doesn't seem to exist.  How does this file get initially created?  I'm assuming that if you make any changes to the claims that are available on the STS, or change the signing certificate, then this file will need to be regenerated.  I didn't set up the STS, so I'm not sure if a step was missed.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the claims you expose, certificate etc, via there configuration GUI for ADFS 2.0, it will be automatically regenerated for you.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f04d49c3-dab6-4d57-9765-20b124b60fb5/adfs-20-federationmetadataxml-file-location?forum=winserver8gen